# SQL Query :count the number of model available for each colour

Tags: sql

count the number of model available for each colour

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT color, count(distinct model) 
  FROM table
 GROUP BY color
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `COUNT` function, for example:

```
  SELECT colour, COUNT(model) 
    FROM articles
ORDER BY colour
```

You can see the use of `COUNT` function here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp

Comment: This SQL is not valid, you need a group by